# A function inside of the h1 tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to insert my function inside of the h1 tag so it will address the user a greeting depending on the time of day. This is my time function but how do I implement it into h1?

```
var today = new Date();
var curHr = today.getHours();
function greeting() {
if ( curHr < 12) {
    document.write('Good Morning');
} else if ( curHr < 18) {
    document.write('Good Afternoon');
} else if ( curHr < 20) {
    document.write('Good Evening')
} else {
    document.write('Good Night');
}
}
```

Comment: are u looking to print messages inside h1 tag ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 2):

You give your H1 an ID

```
<h1 id="goeshere">Message</h1>
```

You then replace `document.write` with something like

```
document.getElementById('goeshere').textContent = 'Good Morning'.
```

and do that for all the conditions.

You do **not** put the javascript inside the H1, and you do **not** use `document.write`, ever !

```js
var today = new Date();
var curHr = today.getHours();
function greeting() {
    if ( curHr < 12) {
        document.getElementById('goeshere').textContent = 'Good Morning';
    } else if ( curHr < 18) {
        document.getElementById('goeshere').textContent = 'Good Afternoon';
    } else if ( curHr < 20) {
        document.getElementById('goeshere').textContent = 'Good Evening';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('goeshere').textContent = 'Good Night';
    }
}

greeting()
```

```html
<h1 id="goeshere">Message</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You put a script that calls it there.

```
<h1><script>greeting()</script></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to write a function that is suppsoed to update the header tag.

You should fetch the date *within* the function (no need in globals). The function should *return* desired value (instead of `document.write`). And you should use the function as appropriate, for example:

```
function greeting() {
  var today = new Date();
  var curHr = today.getHours();
  if ( curHr < 12) {
    return 'Good Morning';
  } else if ( curHr < 18) {
    return 'Good Afternoon';
  } else if ( curHr < 20) {
    return 'Good Evening';
  } else {
    return 'Good Night';
  }
}

var h1 = document.getElementById('my-header');
// Check if such header actually exists
if (h1) {
  h1.innerHTML = greeting();
}
```

It is assumed that the code is executed somewhere *after* the `h1` tag (the tag should be available when we access it), for example:

```
<h1 id="my-header">Default header</h1>
<!-- ... -->
<script>/* here */</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try in such a way also

```
  var today = new Date();
  var curHr = today.getHours();
  function greeting() {
  if ( curHr < 12) {
  return 'Good Morning';
  } else if ( curHr < 18) {
  return  'Good Afternoon';
  } else if ( curHr < 20) {
  return  'Good Evening';
  } else {
  return 'Good Night';
  }
}
 var xyz= greeting()
 //alert(xyz)
 document.getElementById('yourElementId').textContent =xyz
```

have a look at [here is working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/cd62kqz9/8/)

Comment: Just `return`ing something won't display it... And you're not even doing anything in the last 2 `if/else` statements